# org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NAMESPACE_ERR: An attempt is made to create or change an object in a way which is incorrect with regard to namespaces

Tags: spring, jboss, xalan

Bonjour,
I have a problem with the application server JBOSS7 and an application.
This application was developed on the Jetty application server. We have migrated it on JBOSS 7.0.13 final.
After the migration some WS raise the following error message :

> org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NAMESPACE_ERR: An attempt is made to create
>   or change an object in a way which is incorrect with regard to
>   namespaces.

After a long investigation, i found that is the  xalan-2.7.1.jbossorg-1.jar library embedded in the JBOSS7 look to be the origin of this issue. When i replace this library by the "standard" xalan's lib 2.7.1. The Ws works. This solution can be used on the test server, but i can not use it in the target solution.

So, i try to find a better solution. I try to add the xalan lib in my jar, but the jboss lib and the war lib are in conflict. So, i used the **jboss-deployment-structure.xml**  in order to exclude the JBOSS lib. But that does not work.
File extract :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
        <deployment>
           <exclusions>
               <module name="org.apache.xalan"/>
               <module name="org.apache.xerces" />
           </exclusions>
        </deployment>  
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Do you have any suggestion to help me ?

thank you

Mi3

Techno :
Spring 2.5
Jboss 7.0.13.final
java version "1.6.0_29"